# How do i loop a random int that changes in each loop

Tags: c#, loops, random

I want to create a loop that prints out a diffrent random number 10 times. I tried creating a random int in the variable num and then used a for-loop that printed out the variable num 10 times:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

int num = rnd.Next(10);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
       Console.WriteLine(num)
    }
```

This obviously doesn't work since it prints out the same random number 10 times.
How do I get it to output a diffrent number in each loop?

Comment: You need to call the method again for generate the new number. You are using same number in every loop, Check Martin's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put the generation inside the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    int num = rnd.Next(10); // <-- here
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```